# jQuery div animate from left to right and comes back after pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to slide a div from the left to the right side when the 'submit' button is clicked. After a little pause, the div would automatically slides back to it's original position. Currently it goes to the right side but it isn't coming back to the left corner.

CSS

```
#mainform{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    padding-top:20px;
    font-family: 'Fauna One', serif;
}
```

HTML

```
 <div id="mainform">

        <!-- Required div starts here -->
        <form id="form">
            <h3>Contact Form</h3>
            <div class="hello"></div>
           <input type="button" id="submit" value="Send Message"/>
        </form>


    </div>
```

JS

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#submit').click(function(e) {
                reslide();

                function reslide() {
                    $('#mainform').delay().animate({width: '510px', left: '1050'}, 600).delay(5000).animate({width: '510px', right: '1000px'}, 200, function() {
                        setTimeout(reslide, 3000);
                    });
                }
                $('.hello').fadeIn(1500);
                $("<b>Successfully send</b>").appendTo(".hello");
                $('.hello').fadeOut(2500);
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you give feedback to the user after/before submiting, try to use `CSS3 Transform` instead of actually moving/resizing the object.

```
function slide($obj) { // jQuery object of element
    $obj.css("transform", "translateX (50px)");
    setTimeout(function(){
      $obj.css("transform", "none");
    }, 5000);
}
```

To make it smooth (real animation) apply `CSS3 Transition` property.

```
<style>
.object {
    transition: transform 0.6s;
}
</style>
```

Or you can shorten, if you're sure everything'd go smoothly.

```
function slide($obj) { // jQuery object of element
    $obj.animate("transform", "translateX (50px)")
         .delay(600).
         .animate("transform", "translateX (0px)");
}
```

---

PS; in my expirience `jQuery.delay();` wasn't always working with queueing animations, i'm not entirely sure why. As a matter of fact, this happened only sometimes. Sometimes tought it wasn't working

```
// not working
$("smth").animate({"rule":"val"}).delay(500).animate("rule":"val");

// working
$("smth").animate({"rule":"val"})
setTimeout(function(){
   $("smth").animate({"rule":"val"})
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is that, while you add `right` to the element, you also keep `left` with its original value, thus the element will not "come back". Add `left: '',` to the 2nd `animate` function and you should be good to go:

```
function reslide() {
    $('#mainform').delay().animate({
        width: '510px',
        left: '1050'
    }, 600).delay(5000).animate({
        width: '510px',
        left: '',
        right: '1000px'
    }, 200, function () {
        setTimeout(reslide, 3000);
    });
}
```

Here is a fiddle you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/bv8dwaq2/